# Equinox OSGi + JPA Eclipselink + PAX JDBC driver adapter

Tags: jpa, jdbc, osgi, eclipselink, pax

After many problems with "CLASS NOT FOUND" problems in OSGi working with JPA persistence & Eclipse link, I found some article introducing PAX JDBC driver adapter.

Does anybody has some experience with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Pax JDBC should be fairly straightforward to use. Just check out the [docs](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Documentation).

In combination with Eclipselink, you should probably stay clear of the Eclipselink OSGi adapter which has an unnecessary dependency on Eclipse Gemini DBAccess, at least last time I looked at it.

[Pax JPA](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.jpa) is an incubating project which provides OSGi Enterprise compliant adapters for Eclipselink and OpenJPA.

Comment: I found problem in mysql.jdbc bundle which had no class path defined to JDBC class driver (My mistake, I probably overseen this)... I also checked PAX JPA and I think PAX JPA is not necessary now after I changed MYSQL JDBC bundle and Buddy Policy of OSGi bundles. I want to keep it simple: Equinox + Eclipselink JPA+JDBC driver.... I solved all issues now. and everythings works fine.